# Odoo Performance Issue

Tags: postgresql, odoo, odoo-8

Users experienced performance issue, whether it is clicking menus, or saving records, the page just keeps on loading. 
I already did:
Enabled Multi-Processor support for Odoo
PG tune wizard

Server Specifications:
Server specs
Processor: Intel Xeon Processor E3-1240v3 (8MB Cache, 3.40 GHz) 4-Core
Motherboard: Intel Server Board S1200V3RPS (Rainbow Pass)
Memory: 4 x 8GB 1600MHz DDR3L ECC CL11 DIMM 1.35V
Hard Drive: 2 x 3.5in. 2TB 7200RPM 6Gb/s SATA Enterprise drive
RAID: R1

Number of simultaneous users: 15 - 20
Database size: 30.5MB

The Odoo instance has been up since October last year and the issue started only last week.

Thanks

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info then **[edit]** your question and add the missing information.

Comment: Post the contents of your configuration file